# How to get the textbox changed value for Update in @Html.ActionLink in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to get the textchanged value from textbox to update in my Controller.
View

```
  @Html.TextBox("Quantity", item.Quantity)

  <a  href="@Url.Action("Update", "Shopping", new { id = Request.QueryString["UserID"], productid = item.ProductID, qty ="Quantity", unitrate = item.Rate })">     
<img alt="updateitem" style="vertical-align: middle;" height="17px" src="~/Images/product_updates_image.png"
 title="update" id="imgUpdate" />
</a>
```

And in My Controller with Update

```
 public ActionResult Update(string id, string productid, int qty, decimal unitrate)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                int _records = UpdatePrice(id,productid,qty,unitrate);
                if (_records > 0)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index1", "Shopping");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("","Can Not Update");
                }
            }
            return View("Index1");
        }
```

Update Function

```
public int UpdatePrice(string id,string productid, int qty, decimal unitrate)
    {
        con.Open();        
        var total = qty * unitrate;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update [Cpecial_Shopping_Cart_tbl] Set Price='"+ total +"' where [User ID]='" + id + "' and [Product ID]='" + productid + "'", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total", total);
        return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

I passed the Textbox name for the quantity variable in `@Html.ActionLink`. But when the text box value is changed, value is not passed in it.

EDIT :

Initially the value for the textbox from DB is 1. When I change the textbox value, its not getting updated and the same value is updated even when the form is posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a form to send (POST) values from a View into a controller.

This is a rough example:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Shopping", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "myHtmlForm" }))
{
    @Html.Hidden("id", Request.QueryString["UserID"]);
    @Html.Hidden("productid", item.ProductID)
    @Html.Hidden("unitrate", item.Rate)

    @Html.TextBox("qty", item.Quantity)

    <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('myHtmlForm').submit();">
        <img alt="updateitem" style="vertical-align: middle;" height="17px" src="~/Images/product_updates_image.png"
            title="update" id="imgUpdate" />
    </a>
}
```

Comment: @Html.TextBox("qty", item.Quantity) takes the database value only and not the changed textbox value

Comment: No. That is a textbox. When the user clicks on the image, it will submit the changed textbox value

Comment: item.quantity gets only the value from model and not the entered text in Textbox

Comment: At first it takes only the value from the model. But when you submit the form it actually post whatever value is in the textbox.